# How to return an existing XML-file on GET-request (FLASK)

Tags: python, xml, flask

I am currently struggling with some Python Flask code. I have an existing xml-file that has some values in it that I want to send whenever a GET-request is done on a certain URL.

I can't seem to get my already existing XML to be sent back to the client that sent the GET-request. Could anyone help me out?

```
from app import app
from flask import request, Response, render_template, make_response


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World, this is the index page"

@app.route('/inventory')
def inventory():
    if(request.method == "GET"):
        #Here should the return happen of the existing xml-file
```

My XML-file is not located in the same directory as this code is.
If this code is in "localhost/app/routes.py" then the xml-file is in "localhost/resources/resources.xml".

I tried different things, but none seemed to work (with flask's Response, render_template, make_response,..).

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really sure if this is what you're looking for, but ``requests`` can be used to send GET requests and return the response. From there you could fetch XML contents on the server and I have seen requests used in combination with flask in the past, so I make the assumption that requests would be appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but the problem is that I can't seem to place the XML-file in the response message to the GET-request..

Comment: Well I'm not too familiar with Flask, but you don't seem to be specifying the location of the XML anywhere. Maybe its location should be in the @app route or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something:

by using the Flask import objectify I can read XML-files as an object, and then adjust it. When done I can simply convert it back to a string formatted in XML.